# Passing values into different steps in Cucumber in Protractor

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber

I need to pass value from one step to another step in step definition files in cucumber with Protractor Typescript
Generic Example:

```
When('the user enters the value {string}',    function() {

//code written to enter the value
}) 

Then('the user has entered the value') 
{
// I need the value entered in the previous step to be validated here
}
```

Comment: Add more info, so we understand you

Comment: Thanks for the reply George. I have edited my question with a generic example.

Answer (score 1):

```
let inputText = ''
When('the user enters the value {string}', function(string) {
  inputText = string
  //code written to enter the value
}) 

Then('the user has entered the value', function() {     
  expect().to.xxx(inputText)
  // I need the value entered in the previous step to be validated here
})
```